# Schema design for inner documents to help in searching

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for advice on how to proceed with a design issue with MongoDB.
I have a User document with inner documents.

```
public class User
{
  public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  public List<Skills> SkillLists{get;set;} 
  public string xxxx {get;set;}
  public string yyyy  {get;set;}
  public string zzzzz {get;set;}
}

public class UserSkills
{
  public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
  public ObjectId UserId {get;set;} // contains reference to UserId
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  public List<string> Skills {get;set;} This is just an array of strings to help me search
}
```

I am keeping a separate collection to help me search for users with specific skills.
My question is , since my app has the ability to let user change the username,do i need to update all the UserSkills records with the new username ?

Am i not designing the schema right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, you are trying to shoehorn SQL like structure to MongoDB.

MongoDB/NoSQL standard model for one to many relationship is via embedding sub documents
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

How you create classes in your application is up to you, but the map to the storage layer probably wants a user to look like this:

You may want a document that looks like this:

```
{
   _id: "...",
   UserName: "Joe Bookreader",
   Skill: [
            {
              Name: "Microsoft Word",
              level: "Expert
            },
            {
              Name: "Linux",
              level: "Novice"
            },
          ],
   xxxx: "",
   yyyy: "",
   zzzz: ""
 }
```

then

> db.users.find({"Skill.Name":"Microsoft Word"})

returns the entire document.

That way a change to the Username has no impact on the skill list

Comment: Thanks, if the user has a list of education then that would go into the user document too ? the reason why i was designing in separate documents is because i read somewhere that its not a good idea to keep updating/deleting "from" documents. People can update their skills, education and other "attributes" regularly. Do you see a problem with this ?

Comment: Only you can speak to your performance bottlenecks, and you are correct in that there is a slight performance penalty in updating big documents.  The under-the-hood representation (BSON) is immutable, therefore an update is really an insert of the new document and a delete on the old document.  I don't see any reason that the idea you propose would involve heavy IO unless you have 100k+ of users very frequently updating data.  For reference, I have a very similar schema, but about 50 keys where you have 6 so far.  It performs well on commodity hardware performing ~5 updates per second.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, it does not look like there is any need to embed the `UserID` and `UserName` fields in the `UserSkills` collection.  Looking at this logically, a skill is not necessarily unique to an individual.  Users can presumably have multiple skills, and multiple users can probably have the same skill, so making the `UserID` or `UserName` and attribute of the skill makes no sense.

You are probably better off having two collections, `Users` and `Skills` and nesting references to skills within the user documents.  You can index a key within the `Users.Skills` subdocument to make searching easier.